# Creating a marker on one line graph of many graphs of one plot using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am creating graphs on one plot but cannot figure out how to put markers on only one line graph.

This is the current line of code.

```py
df.plot(x="Time", y=["Xbar", "CL", "UCL", "LCL"], 
        kind="line", color=["b", "k", "r", "r"])
```

[image]

I can add markers to all the lines by adding `marker="o"`.

```py
df.plot(x="Time", y=["Xbar", "CL", "UCL", "LCL"], 
        kind="line", color=["b", "k", "r", "r"], marker="o")
```

[image]

How can I change this so only the blue line has the markers and the rest of the lines are unchanged?

Comment: Please post code in code blocks rather than in pictures. Explanation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12131013

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) parameter while plotting the pandas plot to set a particular plot to show both line and marker. The other lines can be set to nothing (`'-'`). Do be careful to set the correct line. Example shown below..

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':list(range(10)),
                 'Xbar': np.random.randint(1,10, size=(10)),
                 'CL': [5]*10,
                 'UCL': [9]*10,
                 'LCL': [1]*10,
})
df.plot(x='Time', y=['Xbar', 'CL', 'UCL', 'LCL'], kind='line', color=['b','k','r','r'], style=['o-','-','-','-'])
```

[image]

Comment: Great to hear. If that answered your question, please accept the same by clicking on the green tick mark next to the answer